# can't get converted value by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

I am doing a conversion rgb to hsl. But I dont get any value.It just say "[object Object]". I know I am doing something wrong. But I can't find what is going wrong. Here is **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/bvamfvq0/)** and here is the codes:

```
$(function() {
    function hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue) {
        if (hue < 0) hue += 6;
        if (hue >= 6) hue -= 6;
        if (hue < 1) return (t2 - t1) * hue + t1;
        else if(hue < 3) return t2;
        else if(hue < 4) return (t2 - t1) * (4 - hue) + t1;
        else return t1;
    } 
    function hslToRgb(hue, sat, light) {
        var t1, t2, r, g, b;
        hue = hue / 60;        
        if ( light <= 0.5 ) {
          t2 = light * (sat + 1);
        } else {
            t2 = light + sat - (light * sat);
        }
        t1 = light * 2 - t2;
        r = hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue + 2) * 255;
        g = hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue) * 255;
        b = hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue - 2) * 255;
        return {r : r, g : g, b : b};
    }
    document.getElementById("slidevalue2").innerHTML = hslToRgb(0, 100, 50);
});
```

Comment: because that is what happens when you call object.toString()

Answer (score 2):

When you set innerHTML's value to an Object it calls toString() on it and you get [Object object]. So the solution depends on how you want it to be outputted.

You can call JSON.stringify

```
document.getElementById("slidevalue2").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(hslToRgb(0, 100, 50));
```

or you can reference the pieces

```
var parts = hslToRgb(0, 100, 50);
document.getElementById("slidevalue2").innerHTML = "r:" + parts.r + " g: " + parts.g + " b: " + parts.b;
```

or you can define [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

```js
var obj = { 
  r:1,
  b:2,
  toString : function () {
      return "r: " + this.r + " b:" + this.b
  }
};

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = obj;
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`hslToRgb()` is returning an object, not a string. Maybe you want to try `document.getElementById("slidevalue2").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(hslToRgb(0, 100, 50));`?